# Get total Latency - UDP Audio Communication

Tags: networking, audio, udp, latency

Okay  i am currently trying to make a Voice chat software using NAudio and c#.

But i currently have a problem, latency seems to bet worse and worse the longer the application runs.

Now, i am a total beginner, so i have no idea what can be the cause of it.

But to troubleshoot, i would like to know if i can get the total latency to see how much it adds over time.

Total Latency = Input buffer + network latency + output buffer (and more if there is any, i am using UDP).

So if i have something like:

Label.text = TotalLatency();

It will get updated all the time.

```
            while (!bStop)
            {
                byte[] datanbefore = waveStream.GetBuffer();

                autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
                waveStream.Position = 0;
                captureBuffer.Read(offset, waveStream, halfBuffer, LockFlag.None);
                readFirstBufferPart = !readFirstBufferPart;
                offset = readFirstBufferPart ? 0 : halfBuffer;

                //TODO: Fix this ugly way of initializing differently.

                //Mute Mic when button is checked
                if (MuteMic.Checked)
                {
                    waveStream = new MemoryStream(halfBuffer);
                }

                byte[] datanaudio = waveStream.GetBuffer();
                udpClient.Send(datanaudio, datanaudio.Length, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 5550);


            }
```

So here is the sending part. I am not really sure how the buffering works, as i started the application using a free sample, and have been changing it here and there, but some parts still remain, but i think that buffer can be improved though.

```
  while (!bStop)
            {

                //Receive data.
                byte[] byteData = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);
                waveProvider.AddSamples(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);


            }
```

Here is the Receive part, and it´s much simpler, it just get´s the data from the UDP, ass it to a buffer and play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out roughly the input and output latency by knowing the buffer sizes of WaveIn and WaveOut. By default in NAudio they are each 100ms.
For network latency, you could try timestamping your audio packets although the clocks of both machines would need to be in sync.

Comment: Yeah noticed that, andi  set to 4ms, then i could just get the Buffered Providers (Buffer Duration), and add that to it.